# How to take the screen shot of what is visible through a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am creating a javascript file which when executed on console it will create a div. And I want to capture what is visible through the canvas / div. But the image that is being captured is blank.
Below is the code which I have written:

```
Start();
function Start() {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "mainBtn");
    button.innerHTML = "+";
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    button.style.textTransform = "uppercase";
    button.style.position = "absolute";
    button.style.top = "50px";
    button.style.left = "100px";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
        .appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', CreateBox);
}
function CreateBox() {
    var button = document.getElementById("mainBtn");
    button.style.display = "none";
    console.log("hello")
    var mainBox = document.createElement("div");
    mainBox.setAttribute("id", "mainBox");
    mainBox.style.position = "absolute";
    mainBox.style.top = "50px";
    mainBox.style.left = "130px";
    mainBox.style.width = "400px";
    mainBox.style.height = "400px";
    mainBox.style.boxSizing = "border - box";
    mainBox.style.zIndex = "99";
    mainBox.style.display = "block";
    mainBox.style.border = "10px solid rgb(222, 221, 221)";
    var cover = document.createElement("div");
    cover.setAttribute("id", "cover");
    cover.style.position = "relative";
    cover.style.width = "100%";
    cover.style.height = "100%";
    mainBox.appendChild(cover);
    var capture = document.createElement("canvas");
    capture.setAttribute("id", "capture");
    capture.style.width = "100%";
    capture.style.height = "calc(400px - 50px)";
    capture.style.display = "block";
    capture.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    cover.appendChild(capture);
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id", "capture-btn");
    button.innerHTML += 'Click to enquiry';
    button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(222, 221, 221)";
    button.style.border = "none";
    button.style.width = "101%";
    button.style.height = "50px";
    button.style.fontWeight = "600";
    button.style.fontSize = "25px";
    button.style.position = "absolute";
    button.style.left = "-1px";
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    button.addEventListener('click', takeScreenshot);
    cover.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
        .appendChild(mainBox);
}

function takeScreenshot() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('capture');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("capture"), 0, 0);
    console.log(ctx);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);
    var box = document.getElementById('mainBox');
    box.style.display = "none";
    CreateForm();
}

function CreateForm() {
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var enquiryForm = document.createElement("div");
    enquiryForm.setAttribute("id", "enquiry-form");
    enquiryForm.style.position = "absolute";
    enquiryForm.style.top = "30px";
    enquiryForm.style.right = "500px";
    enquiryForm.style.width = "400px";
    enquiryForm.style.boxSizing = "border - box";
    enquiryForm.style.zIndex = "99";
    enquiryForm.style.border = "10px solid rgb(222, 221, 221)";
    enquiryForm.style.display = "block";

    var formImage = document.createElement("div");
    formImage.setAttribute("class", "form-image");
    formImage.style.width = "100%";
    formImage.style.height = "350px";
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("class", "form-image");
    image.src = "";
    image.style.width = "100%";
    image.style.height = "350px";
    formImage.appendChild(image);

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "form-details");
    form.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(222, 221, 221)";
    form.style.color = "black";
    form.style.padding = "10px";
    form.style.fontSize = "15px";
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");

    // Create an input element for Full Name
    var FN = document.createElement("input");
    FN.setAttribute("type", "text");
    FN.setAttribute("name", "FullName");
    FN.setAttribute("placeholder", "Full Name");
    FN.style.width = "100%";
    FN.style.height = "32px";
    FN.style.borderRadius = "5px";

    // Create an input element for date of birth
    var DOB = document.createElement("input");
    DOB.setAttribute("type", "text");
    DOB.setAttribute("name", "phone");
    DOB.setAttribute("placeholder", "Phone no.");
    DOB.style.width = "100%";
    DOB.style.height = "32px";
    DOB.style.borderRadius = "5px";

    // Create an input element for emailID
    var EID = document.createElement("input");
    EID.setAttribute("type", "text");
    EID.setAttribute("name", "emailID");
    EID.setAttribute("placeholder", "E-Mail ID");
    EID.style.width = "100%";
    EID.style.height = "32px";
    EID.style.borderRadius = "5px";

    // create a submit button
    var s = document.createElement("button");
    s.innerHTML = "Submit"
    s.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    s.style.width = "100%";
    s.style.height = "32px";
    s.style.cursor = "pointer";
    s.style.borderRadius = "5px";

    // Append the full name input to the form
    form.appendChild(FN);

    // Inserting a line break
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

    // Append the Phone to the form
    form.appendChild(DOB);
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

    // Append the emailID to the form
    form.appendChild(EID);
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
    form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());


    // Append the submit button to the form
    form.appendChild(s);
    enquiryForm.appendChild(formImage);
    enquiryForm.appendChild(form);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
        .appendChild(enquiryForm);
}
```

The screenshot function is:

```
function takeScreenshot() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('capture');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("capture"), 0, 0);
            console.log(ctx);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(dataURL);
            var box = document.getElementById('mainBox');
            box.style.display = "none";
            CreateForm();
        }
```

When I am opening the dataURL it is showing me a blank image, which I suppose is happening because the div/canvas element is empty with no styling and background image. This is what the image looks like.
[image]

**How can I implement this feature where I can capture the screen shot of what is visible through a div / canvas using javascript?**

Comment: You already asked this a couple of hours ago, so what exactly justifies a new question about this now? Especially considering that you got feedback to your original question already.

Comment: @CBroe This question is new as it doesn't tackle with the three.modules.js library it is for any general website and the suggestion posted on the previous question is not working on this question. So kindly remove the duplicate tag.